# NodeJS and dropping privileges temporarily

Tags: node.js, privileges, elevated-privileges, setuid

I am looking for a way to drop process privileges and get them back after doing some operations. Usually it is done using the `setresuid` system call, here is an example in Python, however it also works in C, Rust, Ruby & Go:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# run this as root (i.e. through sudo)
import os

# switch to userid 1000
os.setresuid(1000, 1000, -1)
os.system("id")

# switch back to root
os.setresuid(0, 0, -1)
os.system("id")
```

As of Node 17, I could not find the `setresuid` calls required in the API docs. Did I miss something or does Node just not implement those calls?

If so, is there another way to drop privileges *and them back*?

My current approach is simply doing the following, yet it will throw an EPERM error when I try to get back my root privileges...

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
// Note: Run with root privileges.
// Note: This does NOT work.

const process = require('process')
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const gid = 1000
const uid = 1000

if (process.getuid && process.setuid) {
    console.log(`Current uid: ${process.getuid()}`)
    try {
        process.seteuid(uid)
        process.setuid(uid)
        console.log(`New uid: ${process.getuid()}`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Failed to set uid: ${err}`)
    }

    try {
        process.seteuid(0) // order does not matter here, 
        process.setuid(0)  // won't work, no matter what's first.
        console.log(`New uid: ${process.getuid()}`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Failed to set uid: ${err}`)
    }
}
```